# Are there any ways to get an element as a function in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, each, factory

I'm having confused since I noticed that these 2 following cases are not giving the same result as I expected;

```
console.log(typeof document.querySelector('.holder'));
console.log(typeof $('.holder'));
```

The browser says those 2 cases are the same variable types, an `object`. But when I try to add an `.each` method, it says **`document.querySelector('.holder')` is not a function.**

```js
    'use strict'
    const createMenuTable = (root, clips) => {
      return root.each(() => {
        console.log(root);
      })
    }
    let myTable = createMenuTable(
      document.querySelectorAll('.table'), 
      document.querySelector('.layerGroup')
    ); // When I change the `root` argument to the `$('.table')`, it runs w/o an error.
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="layerGroup">
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Uncaught TypeError: root.each is not a function

My goal is to get an `element` as a function using normal JavaScript like how jQuery does, but have no idea how to solve this problem.

It would be appreciated that somebody could explain me why those 2 cases aren't giving the same results even their type of variables are same.

Comment: "The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned." so yes that would be true https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: People need to learn that JavaScript != jQuery, they're not the same thing. This is a common misunderstanding for developers who skip primary steps of JS learning and start messing around with too many frameworks and libs...

Comment: "When I change the `root` argument to the `$('.table')`, it runs w/o an error." Yes so then it is a jQuery https://api.jquery.com/each/ via the class selector https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss The pure JS is a bit complicated as a person who hasn't used at once ._. Thank you for commenting

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I feel I should've learned JS as a basis, not jQuery lol

Comment: `var element = document.querySelector(".myclass"); //first element with that class, null if none exist.`

Comment: jQuery IS JavaScript, just wrapped as a library that does stuff in a consistent manner (less needed today than when created but still has usefulness as it simplifies some code still) SO if you wish, you can download it in the un-minified form and look it over to learn some things that it does.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I'll keep that.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.layerGroup') == $('.layerGroup').get(0)` returns `true` for a document where one matching node does exist as does `document.querySelectorAll('.layerGroup')[0] == $('.layerGroup').get(0)` if that helps :)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Much Appreciated!

Comment: @sniffingdoggo You should bookmark https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/, they provide full documentation for all things javascript. For example, [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) Using this resource you can see what the underlying type actually is and what methods and properties are available on any given type.

Comment: Additionally you can tie this together with jQuery by referencing the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which doesn't have any method like `each` but you can use [`NodeList#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) method for this purpose.

```
return root.forEach((ele) => {
   console.log(ele);
})
```

---

In jQuery there is [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method which only works with the jQuery object so you can make a common solution by wrapping the collection by jQuery.

```
return $(root).each((i, ele) => {
   console.log(ele);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for answering solution and explanation. Like I said on the above but as a person who learned the code very first as jQuery basis, normal JS is a bit tricky for me lol.

Comment: @sniffingdoggo you should really take the time to learn how javascript ticks. jQuery is just a library in javascript and it follows all of the same rules, it just adds its own. If you learn javascript it removes a bit of the magic and makes your life much easier, even with jQuery

Comment: @sniffingdoggo  :  even I'd started from jQuery first, later it took a while to understand vanila JS and DOM

Comment: @Marie That's why I'm trying to make the code w/o jQuery. I felt like I needed to learn abut original JS.

Comment: @PranavCBalan Your background reduces my worries. I thought that I was the only one who were started the code from jQuery.